# Recover Bitcoin From Transaction ID

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery, lost-bitcoins, recover-private-key

Back in 2013 I bought some bitcoin for a relatively low price, and stored them in an Electrum wallet on my PC. However, I changed PCs a year or two later, and forgot to copy the bitcoin wallet over.

Given the current soaring price, I now have a renewed interest in trying to recover these seemingly lost bitcoins.

I took a screenshot of the blockchain.info page that was displayed shortly after the transaction was completed. I believe this shows the transaction ID, plus the wallet Id it was transferred to.

Here's an edited version of the page I screenshotted, obviously with the IDs hidden so no-one else steals them :)

[image]

I've tried revisiting this website, based on the previous URL, which I believe was the transaction Id. I receive an error: Invalid Transaction Hash

Now, obviously bitcoin has split in two, and this was pre-split.

So, what are the various values that are shown on the screenshot (top left appears to be transaction id, bottom right is my wallet id?)

And can any of this be used to rescue the bitcoins?

Comment: The ONLY thing you need to recover your coin is the Private Key.  That will (obviously) not be visible on a public website.   You'll have to find your Private Key somewhere on your own harddrive (or paperwallet, or other backup)

Comment: @abelenky That's not correct. For deterministic wallets, such as Electrum, the wallet seed can be used to recover the wallet.

Comment: I don't remember getting a wallet seed (is that the 10 words it automatically generates for you?) or at least I didn't note one down. I know what the password would be, if that is of any use.

As for private key, no idea. If I ran Electrum on the same PC, would it use the same private key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the information in the screenshot is publicly available.
And no, they won't be useful for recovering your Bitcoin.

If you used Electrum, you either need the wallet, the recovery phrase(seeds) or the private key(s) to recover you Bitcoins. Note that when you first create your wallet, you are instructed to write down the seed (12 or 13 dictionary words), so if you followed the instructions and still have the seed you can recover the wallet.

[image]